# Join Rows from one huge SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Many Questions like this are already on stackoverflow but with my min knowledge of SQL i can not put it together.

My table looks like this. I have 1000 Player_Id's and 200 Stat_Id's

```
PlayerID  | StatsID  | StatValue   
==================================
1         |   1      |    99
1         |   2      |    31
1         |   3      |    1
2         |   1      |    102
2         |   2      |    1
2         |   3      |    33
3         |   1      |    0
3         |   2      |    1
3         |   3      |    3,4
```

And I would like to get a array of users where one User object looks like this:

```
{playerId:1, stats:{"1":99, "2":31, "3":1, ...}}
```

I have tried a lot but nothing is close to what I want to get done. With this SQL i got my best result:

```
SELECT `PlayerID`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(`StatsID` SEPARATOR ', ') 
  FROM `player_stats` 
  WHERE 1 group by `PlayerID`
```

Here is the Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 15895
        [stats] => 1, 2, 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 21307
        [stats] => 1, 2, 3
    )
```

How can I bring the StatValue Columns into my Query?
Would it be better to generate the desired object after the SQL Query or with multiple Queries?

Performance is not very crucial but of course it would be nice if generating the "playerId-array" would not take ages.

Thanks!

Comment: You're attempting to represent flag sql data/results in a hierarchical manner.  While possible, I generally find this much more straight forward to do on the server side.  Unfortunately I don't know enough about PHP or mySql to actually help with literal implementation.  but in something like MS SQL you ***could*** return XML or JSON to represent hierarchical data, but I'd still rather do it with objects on the server.

Comment: use php and loop through your output , explode the stats and use second loop to recreate the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just add the columns to the `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT `PlayerID`, GROUP_CONCAT(`StatsID`, ':', StatValue SEPARATOR ', ') as stats
FROM `player_stats` 
GROUP BY `PlayerID`;
```

Comment: Wow thanks! That was perfect! I added "AS Stats" behind the braces!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT `PlayerID`, `StatsValues` FROM (
    SELECT `PlayerID`, CONCAT(`StatsID`, ',', GROUP_CONCAT(`StatsValues` SEPARATOR ', ')) AS `StatsValues`
    FROM tblName
    GROUP BY `PlayerID`, `StatsID`);
```